# Add Google GData to xcodeproject for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, gdata

I want to add the GData api from google to receive all the links in a youtube channel. I've followed this tutorial http://mischneider.net/?p=377#comment-1277 but the folder headers is not created. I've been trying the whole day to get it running but without succes. The Google tutorial is not really clear to beginners.

Thnx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this tutorial. You must include SystemCongiguration framework and make all of this tutorial.